# Postgresql fulltext search for words with few specific chars

Tags: postgresql

here is problem. When execute this:

```
select to_tsvector('simple', 'a.')
```

I god just one result: 'a'
because "." is a "Space symbol"

So, my question is what is the best way to remove a few chars from a space symbol list,
for this (simple) dictionary or another (newly created).
I can not find system db, or a file where postgresql store those symbols.

Comment: Stating the problem may help.

Comment: First one was fail I was trying to make reply on already posted question. Now I have created a new one.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create your custom text search configuration

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION your_fts (
    PARSER = pg_catalog."default" );
```

and then add a mapping for blank tokens

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION name
    ALTER MAPPING FOR blank WITH simple;
```

This way you all spaces and special chars will go to tsvectors. Which is probably not what you want. You will need to use [custom dictionary](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-createtsdictionary.html) or even  [custom parser](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-createtsparser.html) to distinguish your few special chars.